# Extract all tar.bz2 files to a directory

Tags: bash

I have many tar.bz2 files in a directory, and would like to extract them to another directory.

Here is my bash script:

```
for i in *.tar.bz2 do; 
sudo tar -xvjf $i.tar.bz2 -C ~/myfiles/
done
```

It doesn't work. How can I make it work? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your variable `$i` contains the entire file name (as you have applied the regex `*.tar.bz2`). So inside your `for loop` you don't need to attach the extension.

**Try:**

```
for i in *.tar.bz2; do 
    sudo tar -xvjf "$i" -C ~/myfiles/
done
```

You also have `;` misplaced.

Comment: Thanks, but `bash: syntax error near unexpected token sudo`